# Synonyms of "down the memory lane" "old is gold"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

Are there any synonyms which could be used in place of "down the memory lane" or "old is gold"? People use these as either a caption, or as the title of the album. Can there be more synonyms similar to the two I just mentioned above?

Comment: *down memory lane* and *old is gold* are not synonymous. So are you looking for two synonyms? One for *down memory lane* and one for *old is gold*?

Comment: @Jim yes, I know these are not synonyms of each other. Yeah, I am looking for the words similar to these two

Answer (score 2):

"We were just reminiscing" can be substituted for "We were just taking a stroll down memory lane" as can "we were just reliving the good old days"

"They don't make 'em like they used to." or "They don't make 'em like that anymore" can sometimes be said in the same situations as "old is gold".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rhyme that hits on the "old is gold" idea:
Make new friends, but keep the old,
One is silver and the other gold.

And another saying, which I think started In regards to songs (recorded music), but is now applied to any kind of thing:  "an oldie but a goodie"

As for Memory Lane, here is a phrase to describe someone who seems to spend too much time there (reminiscing);

"He's living in the past"

And to refer to that particular "golden era" that such people seem to want to preserve or re-create (usually their teen years, their coming-of-age years:

"{He is/She is/They are} stuck in the {'60s/70s/'80s/etc}"

Answer (score 0):

There’s so many other ways to say “old but gold” such as “classic but timeless” or to make it more colloquial “old school but cool” should do.

Answer (score -1):

...maybe? It would really depend on the sentence in question. Sometimes the only thing that will fit is "going down memory lane" (not "*the* memory lane," but just "memory lane" -- like you don't "go down the Second Street" but instead you "go down Second Street").

(To digress: When a street has a proper name, you will usually just use that name: "Go down Second Street, turn right onto Maple Lane, pass by Pine Court, and turn left onto the highway. Get off at Exit 9, and bear right onto Firebrook Road." ("the highway" doesn't have its name listed, so it gets the "the" as being the only highway you're going to see after passing Pine Court.) So even though Memory Lane is metaphorical and often not capitalized like a proper name, it's still a "named street.")